# Is there a Windows terminal app that will colorize certain text strings that appear in the terminal?

Tags: windows-10, terminal, colors, syntax-highlighting

When your command line app pours a lot of text at you, it would be nice if it could colorize the words **ERROR** and **WARNING**.

Anyone found an app that will do that?

Comment: What about piping the output to a log file, and tailing the log with Baretail? Then set up a rule in Baretail to highlight lines which contain those keywords?

Comment: that could be useful in the future - thanks! but I am running up to a dozen cmd windows simultaneously and would like integrated color on each one

Comment: this should be on [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple command line wrappers available out there. Here are a couple:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

https://conemu.github.io/

https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/ - Specifically mentions the functionality you wanted.

I'm sure either of those will do what you want, however, PowerShell is the future, and if you're willing to use it, then I recommend:

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=bgshell

Which will definitely do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) has that feature. It has some predefined sets of words to colorize, like ERROR, WARNING, YES, NO, FAILED, SUCCESS... and of course you can also add your own

> ## Syntax highlighting in terminal
>
> MobaXterm embedded terminal can highlight syntax or use coloration for keywords, even if you are connected to a remote server which does not support colors. This is useful especially when analyzing log files, editing code or trying to detect important keywords. You can even build your own syntax definitions easily.
>
> [image: Mobaxterm color]